# How to subtract across columns

Tags: stata

I want to subtract the values by `apid` in the table below:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| apid  | AB | AS | BS | CS | DS | difference |  
|-------|----|----|----|----|----|----------- |
| AP013 | 43 | 36 |    |    |    | 7          |
-----------------------------------------------
```

For example, for "AP013", the difference is subtracting `AS` from `AB` (43 - 36 = 7).

The new value also needs to be saved in a new column called `diff`.

Can you please tell me how to do this in Stata?

Comment: "does not show any research effort" is the criterion I used in downvoting this. Let me add something positive: to add, subtract, multiply, divide variables (in Stata not called columns), and so forth, use the operators `+ - * /` and so forth. For the list, see `help operators` in Stata.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

You just generate a new variable `diff`:

```
clear

input str5 apid AB AS
"AP013" 43 36
end

generate diff = AB - AS

list

   +------------------------+
   |  apid   AB   AS   diff |
   |------------------------|
1. | AP013   43   36      7 |
   +------------------------+
```